# send file location to a textbox while user clicks on file then application runs

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

My application saves a file with *.SAH type (it is a custom file type). Then i can open it with a file open dialog.

Im wondering how i can send the file location to a textbox when user directly clicks on that file. in other words, the user clicks on the file and then my application runs and on form load, my textbox.text will be the path of file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are good information with examples.

Try editing the registry using *RegCreateKey()* and *RegCloseKey()* apis.